# Remove postgis in order to use pg_upgrade

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade from postgres 9.4 to 9.6 (mac os 10.12) using pg_upgrade. At one point I used postgis in 9.4, but don't need it now. Nevertheless I installed in 9.6 on the theory that it might come in handy.

Now, I have postgis 2.1.5 installed in 9.4:

```
SELECT name, default_version,installed_version                                                                                                                                   FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name LIKE 'postgis%' ;
          name          | default_version | installed_version 
------------------------+-----------------+-------------------
 postgis                | 2.3.0           | 
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 2.3.0           | 
 postgis_topology       | 2.3.0           |
```

But 2.3.0 installed in 9.6:

```
SELECT name, default_version,installed_version                                                                                                                                   FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name LIKE 'postgis%' ;
          name          | default_version | installed_version 
------------------------+-----------------+-------------------
 postgis                | 2.1.5           | 
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 2.1.5           | 
 postgis_topology       | 2.1.5           |
```

I would like to simply get rid of these to proceed with the upgrade (and drop anything that depends on them). How can I do that?

Comment: I guess, this depends on the package manager, you use on MAC OS. Maybe http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is the better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but package management. Maybe migrate it to apple.SE

Comment: have you tried `drop extension postgis;` and so on?

Comment: Hmm... I have a linux system too -- I did put in "mac os" but I think the question is general? "how to unload loaded libraries in postgres"... I guess that an answer may involve programming as it may require a script. Just I can't figure out where the libraries are referenced.

Comment: @JuliaLeder -- yes ... the "available extensions" seem still to be available whether or not the extension is installed in any particular database. I already dropped postgis_template.

Comment: are the available packages have any adverse effects on the rest of the installation? or is it that you just want them gone from the system for some other reason?

Comment: @JuliaLeder -- in fact your idea worked in the end... I thought I had dropped extension already. Wasn't true, but led me to believe that simply being an available extension was enough to cause the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
DROP EXTENSION postgis;
```

in all databases on both clusters.
If that returns an error, it is ok (then PostGIS was not installed to begin with).

After that, everything should be ok for an upgrade.

To see if the extension is installed in a database, you can run the query

```
SELECT oid, extnamespace FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'postgis';
```

Comment: Also hat-tip to @JuliaLeder who suggested in a comment. I have ~50 databases defined in old setup, so just eyeballed them and declared that none use postgis anymore. However ... I was wrong! (Is there a systematic query for this, btw?)

Comment: I added a query to the answer. It should be easy to write a shell script that runs the query in all databases in a cluster.